# Drawing overlapping semi-transparent lines without darkening at overlaps

Tags: canvas, drawing, transparency, overlapping

I have read the post with the same title, and it was useful, but did not answer my question. My drawing program allows the user to freely draw wide lines over an image; however, I don't want the transparency darkening when they overlap lines by drawing in the same space twice.

Is there anyway to draw using canvas lineTo, stroke, strokeStyle etc so that this does not happen. Below is a code snippet to give the idea of what I did:

```
drawPencilDown: function(e, $this)
        {
            $this.ctx.lineJoin = "round";
            $this.ctx.lineCap = "round";
            $this.ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0)";
            $this.ctx.fillStyle   = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)";

            $this.ctx.lineWidth = $this.settings.lineWidth;         
            //draw single dot in case of a click without a move
            $this.ctx.beginPath();
            $this.ctx.arc(e.pageX*sx, e.pageY*sy, $this.settings.lineWidth/2, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
            $this.ctx.closePath(); 
            $this.ctx.fill();
            $this.ctx.beginPath(); 
            $this.ctx.moveTo(e.pageX*sx, e.pageY*sy); 
        },

        drawPencilMove: function(e, $this)
        {
            $this.ctx.lineTo(e.pageX*sx, e.pageY*sy);
            $this.ctx.stroke();
        },

        drawPencilUp: function(e, $this)
        {
            $this.ctx.closePath();
        },
```

Comment: What about drawing all your shapes to alpha 1 and then set your canvas opacity .5 - then you might want to overlap several canvas for different objects sets. SVG would be appropriate for that too

Comment: Use two canvases. A lower one with all the lines so far. A top one for the current line, as mika says set the opacity for the current line. In drawPencilMove store up the positions for the line. In drawPencilUp erase the top canvas and draw the accumulated positions as one line on the lower canvas.

Answer (score 2):

Use `globalCompositeOperation="xor"` and set a `globalAlpha` < 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the  globalCompositeOperation property: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/6_1_canvas_composite.html

Both 
source-atop and
destination-atop would work